# Maven is not using the proper Java compiler 

Tags: java, maven

I'm using Maven 2.2 on Solaris 10.  When compiling my JAR project, in which I want to use a Java 6 compiler, I get compilation errors like …

```
[INFO] Compilation failure

/home/davea/selenium/src/main/java/com/cm/systems/selenium/util/TestSuite.java:[17,18] generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```

(use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
    private Vector filesets = new Vector();

I have changed my $JAVA_HOME to point to my Java 6 installation (there is another Java 5 installation on the system) …

```
-bash-3.00$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
-bash-3.00$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/davea/jdk1.6.0_25
```

Yet still the errors persist.  What else do I need to do?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, the compiler plugin uses [source=1.3](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#standard) and [target=1.3](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options). You have to manually set it to 1.6:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```